# Several of us decided to leave and join company B

Tags: resignation, contracts

Recently five of us from company A were given a far better offer from company B, whose team consists of 15 people who formerly work in A.

Would there be any repercussions if all five of us resigned within the same month and joined company B?

For me personally, I do have a non-compete clause which states that I'm not supposed to entice company A's employees away. I'm in no way doing that but I'm still worried about it.

In what way it could be done so that the current company will not hate us and, do we need to act ignorance to the fact that eachnof us is leaving?

Comment: Were you all looking for a job at the same time and at the same company?

Comment: I should be worried that you might just be `pawns` in their game of "chess". Pawns can be sacrificed. Perhaps the other side of the street will not be as green as you think.

Comment: Relevant off-site reading: [my whole team is going to resign at once](http://www.askamanager.org/2011/11/my-whole-team-is-going-to-resign-at-once.html)

Comment: Well, we have 1 month notice, its a shift job in IT industry

Comment: What I might worry about is if the hiring official (or anyone you know from who previously worked at your current company) who hired you also had a noncompete because in this case it is highly likely to go to court and you could end up losing your job in a settlement. Even when they aren't enforceable, threat of a suit can bring about this type of action. I would stay away from this company for a couple of years at least.  Find a different job elsewhere that doesn't have this Sword of Damocles hanging over it.

Answer (score 2):

> all 5 of us could resign peacefully

That is not going to happen, they're losing a chunk of people in one go. They're not going to be happy about it. It's hard to say what the company will do, but if they're any good they will do something.

There is also a danger that Company B is not all that sincere, they might be trying something else by subverting 5 employees who are now known to have questionable loyalty. This sort of head hunting is quite suspicious in some industries because it's sometimes used to cripple a competitor without actually keeping the employees for long or even really hiring them in some instances.

I would be very wary in your shoes. Legally you may be fine (that's off topic here), but it could impact on your professional reputation and/or your future career.

I haven't seen this happen often, but the last place I worked lost three staff to a competitor, one of which was a senior team leader, within a year all three of those former staff were not only out of their new company but had a lot of trouble getting jobs in the industry if they ever did (I never really heard about them after a while).

Comment: I would think 5 trained staff leaving from one locale would make an impact, whatever their job. But this is in IT, and according to the question, they have already lost 15 to company B, so that's twenty total. I'd be pretty concerned if it was me.

Comment: You raise a good point. The way I'm reading this though, I'm assuming that Company B was started up by disgruntled former employees of A. It's fairly cut-throat ‎but it makes sense for B to hire on competent former colleagues. If that's the case, while it's unlikely that B will let the new employees go after crippling A, there's simply no way for the OP not to burn bridges with his current employer.

Comment: that's possible, also subverting clients, but it's very mercenary and if it falls to bits you're not working with loyal people. In any case your burning bridges part is the salient point. The rest is conjecture.

Answer (score 0):

> would there be implications if all 5 of us resigned within the same month and joined company B?

There might or might not be. You *might* be accused of leading the exodus, but cannot be done so legally. So, you might be leaving some negative impression at Company A, but that's OK unless and until you are happy with the offer from Company B.

> I'm in no way doing that but still I'm worrying about it

You might feel guilty, but the truth is: **You didn't start this.** So, stop being guilty and move on (if you are happy with the offer).

Corporates are always cut-throat, and you wouldn't really progress if you worry about everybody's feelings, and much worse when you are *not* the cause/reason for something.

> any advice so that nothing bad will happen and all 5 of us could
>   resign peacefully

5 people is a lot of lost manpower. So, Company A would definitely try to retain as many as possible like a hike, promotion, perks, etc. So, maybe wait and negotiate wisely with both the companies and make an informed decision.

Answer (score 0):

You obviously feel uncomfortable about the move, hence this post. You understand that you're probably punching company A below the belt. This decision will probably have a very negative affect on the remaining 10 employees in company A.
If the only reason for the move is a "better offer" than take a deep breath and go tell that to your boss. He must understand that the current terms of employment are uncompetitive and be given an option to correct that somehow. If he fails, you'll feel much better about the move.

Answer (score -1):

**Men may come and men may go but companies will be there.**

I heard this text long back when i resigned from my first company. Quality may come down or increase depends on their new replacements. 
Joining the competitors is always risky since they will always have a suspicious eye on you.
Think twice before joining a competitor.